# Creating an image carousel to select a winner with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel

I created the code in an attempt to make a tie between the images and when the carousel stops rotating I would like the drawn image to be in the center of the highlighted carousel, and I also wanted to create the effect to illuminate the image that is passing in the center during the draw.
This is the code I made, for more details see codesandbox

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel3d-with-draw-6gm3cj